# Adding 4 item per row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, do-while

I have some HTML in a variable that I'd like to loop 4 time per row. I am making a couple of queries first. In one I get the number of rows and store it in a variable. The second, I am looking to fetch the associated data that I will need to display.

```
$results = $dbCon->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($results);
$res = $dbCon->query($results);
$data = $res->fetch_assoc();
$link = $data['link'];
$title = $data['title'];
$image = $data['image'];
$imgAlt = $data['imgAlt'];
```

Third, I store what I want to display in a variable. The HTML I plan on displaying looks something like this

```
$html = printf("<div style=\"text-align:center; max-width:270px; white-space:normal; word-wrap:break-word; border-left:1em solid transparent; border-right:1em solid transparent; text-overflow: ellipsis; float:left;\">
        <a href=\"%s\">
            <img style=\"width:270px; height:232px; margin-bottom:40px; border-radius:45px; -moz-border-radius:45px; -webkit-border-radius:45px; box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #fff; -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #fff; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #fff;\" src=\"images/recentshoots/%s\" alt=\"%s\" />
            <p>%s</p> <br /></a>
        </div>", $link, $image, $imgAlt, $title);
```

Next, I would like to loop the 20 items per page in 4 items per row. This is where I am having some trouble. My issue is that the number of characters in the $title are always different so the layout breaks apart. At first a tried a simple way using css and php to do a str_pad() but it doesn't seem to work right with empty spaces. I always get some containers that are taller than others which distorts my row. So I did some research in this platform to model after someone else example.

I m having some trouble with what I found because the examples I've seen have information missing that I need to understand how to modify my own. I have seen it done with foreach and while loops. Can someone help me find a way to understand this better?

How can I loop the data retrieved and make sure that only 4 per row exist in a page of 20 items? Thank you so much for your help. I started with something like this

```
$startingPoint = 1;
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
foreach($startingPoint < 4){ //this foreach is not even starting the right way, how can I fix this?
    echo $html;
}
```

Can I use a foreach? or a while loop? or do-while?

which one is the best solution and the fastest or most efficient way to go? The shorter the code the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can try this code. Full pagination and view:

**Example: index.php**

```
<?php
    //get page id for pagination and limit query
    $limit = 4;
    if(isset($_GET["page"]))
        $page = intval($_GET["page"]);
    else
        $page = 1;

    $total = $limit * $page;
    $start = $total - $limit;

    //GEt data from database. I have used mysqli for testing purpose.
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>


    <!--Your html code what you want-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
         <!--loop inside html-->
        <?php while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['title']; ?></td>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['imgAlt']; ?>"> </td>

                <td><a href="<?php echo $data['link']; ?>">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

<?php
    /**======== Pagination Url generate=============*/
    $totalPages = ceil($total/$limit);
    if($page <=1 ){
        " <span style='font-weight: bold;'> < Prev </span> ";
    }else{
        $j = $page - 1;
        echo " <a href='index.php?page=$j'>Prev</a> ";
    }

    for($i=1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++){
        if($i<>$page){
            echo " <a href='index.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }else{
            echo " <span style='font-weight: bold;'>$i</span> ";
        }
    }
    if($page == $totalPages ){
        echo " <span style='font-weight: bold;'>Next ></span> ";
    }else{
        $j = $page + 1;
        echo " <a  href='index.php?page=$j'>Next</a></span> ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I like what you have here, I just have a few questions. Is there a way to speak via some sort of messenger? My pagination class looks something like this when it is called. '$start = $pagination->prePagination();' and I add it right above my sql query. The limit of the pages is set with $limit. Any suggestions or modifications on your example that could help me further? because your pagination example is great however, what I already have set for it is easy to maintain and reuse. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also where is the best place to add the HTML '<div class="row">' and the closing "</div>" ? should I include it in the $html variable? or before the while statement? I have seen so many examples that it starts to get confusing who's version is right or better or more efficient.

Comment: My pleasure @RookieRecruits.  Don't worry you can use whatever you want that allow php, don't become confused.
I have edited again and initialize a table  for your better understand.
You can use  '<div class="row"> </div>'.  You can use your custom pagination function but the function always contain this type of code that i provided. You can use your own query method and always data will be same.
Sorting you can do inside SqlQuery (order by).

Answer (score 2):

Foreach loops are used for array datatypes whilst a while loop can be used for booleans and more.

What you're looking for is a for loop, this allows your to set a counter and each time the loop is ran it adds to a counter. Once the expression is met, it ends the loop.

```
for($i = 1; $i == 4; $i++)
{
     echo 'Loop ' . $i . ': This will loop 4 times';
}
```

However, you could fix your foreach by using this snippet:

```
$startingPoint = [1,2,3,4];
foreach($startingPoint as $start)
{
     echo $html;
}
```

Since there are 4 items inside the array, the loop will continue 4 times.

Your SQL is returning more than one row of data thus creating $data to become multidimensional, your loop therefore may not work how its written, you could try this:

```
for($i = 1; $i >= $limit; $i++)
{
    print_f(<!-- html here -->, $data[$i]['column']);
}
```

Comment: Should the html "row" class be inside of this loop or outside? Where is best to open and close the tag? right now, it is outside the "printf". Should it be inside the "printf"? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, assuming a row seperates each layer of html, it should be a delmiter of the $html therefore going inside the loop, before and after you print your html. @RookieRecruits

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the row should separate the first 4 iterations of the html from the following 4 an so on until it reaches a total of 20 or 5 rows.

Comment: If you are seperating your cycles then it will go outside the loop. If you want to seperate everything, it goes inside the loop. @RookieRecruits

Comment: I tried it but it is only displaying 1 per page. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Are you sure $data isn't a multidimensional array containing multiple rows of data? If it is, thats where your issue is. You are outputting the same html data each time without updating the mark, ill update my answer. @RookieRecruits

Comment: Thanks, trying to implement it now.